# Firefox loads old src url for img element even after reinstalling

Tags: html, image, firefox, src

In my project I have changed few details:

- 1) Delete folder with logo image.
- 2) Change `src` attribute of `img` corresponding to new location for image.

Old src: "images/logo/logo.png".

New src: "images/logo.png"

But when I load the page, I see an "empty" icon where the logo should be.
I tried to remove cache and I have even reinstalled Firefox. I also tried to switch of my antivirus. 
But when I open debugger, I see old `src` value of `img`. How can I update image in Firefox?

Here is the code:

```
<nav class="col navbar navbar-expand-md mx-auto py-0 align-items-end justify-content-between">
                <a class="navbar-brand p-0 ml-5" href="#"><img id="logo" src="images/logo.png"></a>
                <div class="menu-icon-wrapper d-flex position-relative justify-content-center align-items-center mr-5">
                    <svg class="blue-triangle d-block position-absolute" width="60" height="60" viewBox="0 0 60 60">
                        <polygon points="0,20 40,60 54,6" fill="#00ff65"/>
                    </svg>
                    <div class="open-close position-relative">
                        <svg class="position-absolute" width="100%" height="100%" viewBox="0 0 60 60">
                            <polygon points="0,20 40,60 54,6" fill="#00b4ff"/>
                        </svg>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </nav>
```

Updated:
Other browsers don't see the image too.
I load page localy.

Comment: What server are you running your code on?  Do you have the code/HTML you are using to load the image?  We need more information to answer this question.  Did you try restarting the server after making your change?  It may just be that the server didn't update because it had already loaded/cached the page.

Comment: @jack.benson, I added the code. Also as I found out, other browsers retrieving cached version of page the same way.

Answer (score 0):

Information you have provided regarding the situation looks too less.

I suppose you have changed the source directly in the HTML file. If that's the case open the network monitor and see if HTML file is cached.

- Press  Ctrl + Shift + E ( Command + Option + E on a Mac).
- Select "Network" from the Web Developer menu, (which is a submenu of the Tools menu on OS X and Linux)

If the page is hosted in a server see if your server or the CDN has cached the page.

Hope that helpss. !!

Comment: Are you working locally or testing something live ??

Comment: Thank you for feedback, @Nithin Suresh. I have disabled cache in the debugger. Image still doesn't loads.

Comment: Do one thing, go to the inspector and change the source directly in there and see if you could see the image in the browser.

Comment: Yes, image have appeared, @NithinSuresh

Comment: <img id="logo" src="/images/logo.png"> try adding "/" in front of the source. If you have tried that too, see the CSS for the img tag and see if any CSS rule is getting overridden.

Comment: Concrete for this img element there is only one rule: 
    height: 50px;. And it's not overriden.

Answer (score 0):

Solved. Side script changed logo url.
Thanks to all for trying to help!